# How does from A import B work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a folder C:\Python27\Lib\MyLibs.  In it there is a `__init__.py`.  In the folder is also a utils.py file which contains a function sendMail.

I did a:

```
from MyLibs import utils
```

but I am still unable to call sendMail() directly.  I have to use `utils.sendMail()`.  Is this how it is supposed to work?

I thought I was able to call sendMail() directly in another shell a few days ago.  I can't remember what I did to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: You need to do `from MyLibs.utils import send_mail `

Comment: @karthikr Yes, that's the answer!  Thanks.  `from MyLibs.utils import *` was what I did earlier.

Comment: On that topic, you should avoid the `from xxx import *` pattern. It will only lead you to pain.

Comment: [6.12. The import statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)